# Probability that we have to wait longer for the first instance of a return greater than $R_0$

Tags: probability

Let $R_0$ be the initial one-day return. Let each day's return be i.i.d. random variable. Let $T$ be the random variable denoting the first occurence of a return greater than $R_0$. For any given $t$, what is $P(T>t)$?

This is one of my homework problem. I think $P(T>t)$ equals the probability that theres no return higher than $R_0$ for the first $t$ days, that is, $P(R_i \leq R_0)^t$. However, the distribution of each day's return is not given, so I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Do you think the meaning of "one-day return" plays any part in solving this homework problem?  The meaning (and importance) may be clear to you (from the studies) but it will not be so evident to your Readers here without more context.

Comment: I don't think it's relevant.

Comment: @middlethird_cantor the accepted answer is of very low quality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any given $R_{0}$

$P(R_1 <R_0) = P(R_2 <R_0) = ... = P(R_t <R_0) = q$

Because of the iid assumption. For any given $R_0$ events $R_i <R_0$ are independent. We can recognise "T" as analogy to "number of first success and and derive

$P(T>t) = q^t$

Then for any $R_0$ we can think in terms of integration, variable can go from 0 to 1

$\int_{0}^{1}q^tdq = \frac {1}{t+1}$

Comment: The integral makes no sense in my opinion. I don't get why this got accepted